# attach object element by name javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to attach a javascript function on an object element which is dynamically generated via a wordpress plugin and this is generated only with an element name and not an Id, I am trying to do following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selector').gentleSelect(); // apply gentleSelect with default options
});
</script>
```

But since the element does not have an ID attribute but only the name attribute how can I make this function to work!

I am trying to use gentleselect jquery plugin here!

Thanks
Amit.

Comment: [Attribute Equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: `$("[name='whatever']").gentleSelect()`?

Comment: I tried what you said and on chrome inspect I see the error : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **[attribute equal selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** for that.

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

```
 $('[name=value]').gentleSelect();
```

Comment: Thanks Milind, I tried what you said but no effect :( I've uploaded the full script in the head of my following url,  http://giftsmate.cloudapp.net/home/  Please see if you can check if I am doing something wrong here!

Comment: @user2549857: can you share the fiddle??

Comment: how do i create a fiddle, sorry but unaware buddy, the file is at the url - giftsmate.cloudapp.net/home if that helps, the code is in the head of the html and you can search it by keyword gentle if that helps :)

Comment: Yes Milind, I've created the fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/fapp4/ Please check! Thanks a ton bro!

Comment: Can you add gentleSelect library files in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Rc4Qz/.

Comment: I see that you already have the library files in external resources, they are the same ones, gentleselect is to turn a simple dropdown to a multi column one but isnt seems to be doing so ritenow

Comment: @avenirlabs: but it has the function that we are trying to call. Can you finded the hosted library from their DOC and add it in external resources in fiddle.

Comment: Updated that in the fiddle, but it seems to be the same, you can check it now! http://shawnchin.github.io/jquery-gentleSelect/ thats the one I am trying to use if it helps!

Comment: Hey Milind did you get a chance to take a look buddy!